# Infinite scroll load more videos not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project assignment on this and i have been battling with this for the past hours.
The infinite lord more works for text and posts but not working for fullscreen video slide. Something similar to TikTok and IG reels

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.loadScrollData = function (start, options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            limit: 3,
            listingId: '',
            loadMsgId: '',
            ajaxUrl: '',
            loadingMsg: '<div style:"text-align:center;">Please Wait...!</div>',
            loadingSpeed: 10

        }, options);

        action = "inactive";

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                'getData': 'ok',
                'limit': settings.limit,
                'start': start
            },
            url: settings.ajaxUrl,
            success: function (data) {
                $(settings.listingId).append(data);
                if (data == '') {
                    $(settings.loadMsgId).html('');
                    action = 'active';
                } else {
                    $(settings.loadMsgId).html(settings.loadingMsg);
                    action = "inactive";
                }
            }
        });

        if (action == 'inactive') {
            action = 'active';
        }

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(settings.listingId).height() && action == 'inactive') {
                action = 'active';
                start = parseInt(start) + parseInt(settings.limit);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.fn.loadScrollData(start, options);
                }, settings.loadingSpeed);
            }
        });

    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: What do you mean, by not working properly? How do you expect it to work and what does it now.

Comment: @Grumpy the load isn't working for fullscreen video scroll. It's not getting the appropriate height to trigger the load more